# MsalProvider - dynamic msal config

Tags: dynamic, react-hooks, azure-ad-msal

I follow the tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/javascript/tutorial/single-page-application-azure-login-button-sdk-msal. However, i need to modified the code so that it is able to configure it using the clientId that will be available after  is rendered (msal config is retrieved from app level). Is it possible to update the msalConfig in child component?

```
//index.js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <MsalProvider instance={new PublicClientApplication(MSAL_CONFIG)}>
        <Router>
          <App />
        </Router>
      </MsalProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file named authConfig.js in the src folder to contain your configuration parameters for authentication, and then add the following code:

```
export const msalConfig = {
auth: {
clientId: "Enter_the_Application_Id_Here",
authority: "Enter_the_Cloud_Instance_Id_Here/Enter_the_Tenant_Info_Here", 

redirectUri: "Enter_the_Redirect_Uri_Here",
  },
  cache: {
cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge

    storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge

  }
};

// Add scopes here for ID token to be used at Microsoft identity platform endpoints.

export const loginRequest = {

 scopes: ["User.Read"]

};



// The endpoints here for Microsoft Graph API services you'd like to use.

export const graphConfig = {

   graphMeEndpoint: "Enter_the_Graph_Endpoint_Here/v1.0/me"

};
```

This way you can configure it using ClientID.
Here is the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react).